# Javascript write variable with IF/ELSE and insert it in a other var

Tags: javascript, if-statement, var

i have the following problem:

```
var widowwidth = 0,w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')      [0],x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth;

if( x > 1624) {
        widowwidth = 1800 / (10 + 2);
}
else {
        widowwidth = 800 / (10 + 2);
}
```

now i want to give meterNum the var: windowwidth

```
_drawSpectrum: function(analyser) {
        var that = this,
            canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
            cwidth = canvas.width,
            cheight = canvas.height - 2,
            meterWidth = 10, 
            gap = 10, 
            capHeight = 2,
            capStyle = '#fff',
            meterNum = windowwidth, // <----- HERE
```

is there a simple way or did i some mistake, because it dosen't work :(

Thank you, Tim4497

Comment: You mispelled the variable, in the top code is `widowwidth` - in the bottom its `windowwidth` (on a different note, you should camel case `windowWidth`

Comment: As a matter of good habit: Paste JS code you write into http://jshint.com/. It spots this and many other types of errors.

Comment: your code snippet looks valid but nobody can tell you whether the sematics are correct because the context is not clear. Would you mind elaborating on what exactly the whole problem is? EDIT: oh yeah, and you have a typo 'bout "widowwidth" :-D

Comment: oh hahaha thank you tymeJV and @Tomalak for the tip :) it's now working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the variable initialization and in the if else statements you're defining your variable widowwidth instead of windowwidth. If the variable's other half isn't dead yet, you need to correct this to make it work.